# `read` re-implemented for Int's

Tags: strings, parsing, haskell, reinventing-the-wheel, integer

I have written a safe read function for haskell (for education!). I think this is fairly idiomatic haskell code, but I'd like to know for sure. If you see anything else that could be improved, please let me know in your answer.

```
module ReadNum (readNum) where

main = print $ readNum "87k7"

readNum :: String -> Maybe Int
readNum xs = readNum' $ reverse xs

readNum' :: String -> Maybe Int
readNum' (x:xs) = (\y z -> y + 10 * z) <$> readChr x <*> readNum' xs
readNum' [] = Just 0

chrToNum :: [(Char, Int)]
chrToNum = [('0', 0), ('1', 1),
            ('2', 2), ('3', 3),
            ('4', 4), ('5', 5),
            ('6', 6), ('7', 7),
            ('8', 8), ('9', 9)]

readChr :: Char -> Maybe Int
readChr c = lookup c chrToNum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change I'd make, respecting your overall design, is to refactor `chrToNum` as this:

```
chrToNum :: [(Char, Int)]
chrToNum = zip "0123456789" [0..]
```

Apart from that, if we are willing to slightly alter the design, I would separate the string validation from the computation of the `Int` represented. The string validation can be done using `mapM :: (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]` (this way we avoid explicitly writing the recursion).

```
validateString :: String -> Maybe [Int]
validateString = mapM readChr
```

Then, you can define a function computing the `Int` represented by a list of digits (I use `foldl'` which requires you to add `import Data.List` but you can equally well use `reverse` + `foldr` as you originally did)

```
represents :: [Int] -> Int
represents = foldl' (\ ih z -> 10 * ih + z) 0
```

Finally, putting it all together we get:

```
readNum :: String -> Maybe Int
readNum = fmap represents . validateString
```

Comment: Cool, nice answer! So, `mapM` fails if any of the computations fail?  (for the `Maybe` monad at least)

Comment: Yes. `mapM` has a structure similar to the one of your `readNum'`: `mapM f [] = pure []` and `mapM f (x : xs) = (:) <$> f x <*> mapM f xs`.

Comment: As a minor improvement: `[0..]` -> `[0..9]` to be more explicit.